# Ansible: compare variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to compare some variables so here is my case:

`pg_master_ip` is an ip obviously.

ansible doesn't parse `pg_master_ip`.

`bond0.stdout` is a result of an earlier register task.

If I could use `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_bond0'].ipv4.address }}` I'd be happier but I don't know how.

```
- name: pgsql and pgpool initiate master
  include: master.yml
  when: bond0.stdout == '{{pg_master_ip}}'
```

Thank you for the advice in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][some_variable] }}` is redundant.  You can just use `{{ some_variable }}` instead.  In this case it would be `{{ ansible_bond0.ipv4.address }}`.  If you want a full list of your default facts check out the [setup module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/setup_module.html).

```
ansible $SERVER -m setup
```

Here's how your conditional task should look

```
- name: pgsql and pgpool initiate master
  include: master.yml
  when: ansible_bond0.ipv4.address == pg_master_ip
```

Comment: With Ansible requiring quoting in YAML nowadays, this does not seem to work anymore.